# Bootstrap div won't adapt to height based on content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

*Note: Yes I did make a research first trying to find a solution and tried to implement a number of options to fix the problem, nothing I could find worked though!*

**UPDATE**

Because media queries are not an optimal solution for my problem, as I have to take into account multiple cases of width/height combinations in a responsive layout, I used some javascript at the end in order to calculate the difference in height of the banner div and the content div in order to readjust height accordingly. Here is the code I used

```
function resizeContainers()
{
    var bannerContainer = $('#banner');
    var contentContainer = $('#homeFormContainer');
    var bannerContainerHeight = bannerContainer.height();
    var bannerContainerBottom = $(window).height() - bannerContainerHeight;
    var contentContainerBottom = $(window).height() - contentContainer.height();
    var containersDiff = bannerContainerBottom - contentContainerBottom;
    if (containersDiff > -200) {
        var newBannerContainerHeight = bannerContainerHeight+contentContainerBottom+20;
        bannerContainer.css('height', newBannerContainerHeight);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // check and resize after page loads 
    resizeContainers();

    // check and resize containers on window resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        resizeContainers();
    });
});
```

I am struggling with a div in bootstrap that won't adapt to the height of it's inner content. As far as I can tell, CSS looks OK (but it probably is not, so I could use some help).

You can see the fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/spairus/fbmssraw/6/

The basic HTML structure looks like this

```
    <div id="banner" class="banner">
        <div class="banner-image"></div>
        <div class="banner-caption" style="display: table;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    (content here)
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}
.banner-image {
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.banner:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    content: "";
}
.banner-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
.subfooter {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-top: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
    padding: 40px 0;
}

/* Backgrounds
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.default-bg {
    background-color: #222222;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.space {
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

I need the .banner and .banner-caption to expand along with the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to have the following code:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and then on your main container:

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}
```

the container is *not going to be* responsive to the content inside it, because what you've said in the CSS is basically "hey container (banner), I want you to be 100% of the screen size of whatever device you show up on" .

Instead you need to change the css to said "hey container I want you to have a min-width or be responsive to whatever content you have inside you", so you could do the following:

The best solution I have for this problem (which I face quite often) is as follows.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
     .banner {
    width: 100%;
    height:120%;  // adjust this to whatever size you think your content will stretch to there is no golden rule saying it has to be 100% only.
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
        }
    }
```

### Edit

Why does the above solution work? Notice how I have added a media query that says min width of `992px`, now it's safe to say that the dimension of devices above `992px` are `predictable`, and thus it's safe to use a `height:120%`; it's only when you go below `992px` or `768px` that the screen resolution (height & width) become unpredictable to counter this you add absolutely no styling to the height of the container.

How effective is this technique? Well, it is pretty effective, but on some screens (the screens above `992px`) there might arise a problem of excessive white spacing or slight overlapping of content.

Now to counter this problem you can use multiple media queries : eg.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
       height : 125 %;
    }

    /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
       height : 120 %
    }

    /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
       height : 100 %
    }
```

but IMHO, this is not needed unless you need pin point accuracy (multiple media queries are a pain!). Worst case scenario, use two media queries.

Anyway, here's the technique in [action](http://jsfiddle.net/49g6qw9d/). Try to reduce the screen size and voila! Still looks pretty, and nowhere have a added `height:400%` for smaller screens: it adapts by itself.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks. This is one of the options I tried. Unfortunately it will not work, as it is impossible to have a "fixed" height (for example 120%) because that creates inconsistencies across different screen sizes. For example, my content with height:100% fits perfectly on a full hd monitor, but when I use a laptop with lower res (i.e. 1280*768) the content overlaps the content below. If I give more height, the content will have too much empty space on the large monitor. If I completely remove the banner div all works. There should be another way to make this responsive, I hope...

Comment: @mspir , ur dead right when u say "theres gonna be extra empty space" on some screens and "on some screens content will overlap" , thats the reason , i suggested using a media query that checks for a minimum width of 992px , for smaller screens you surely want the .banner to expand to whatever height the content is .. this is't the perfect solution though , but that what i usually do anyways , after testing on a reasonable number of devices . :) you can wait and see if there is a better way .

Comment: So you mean I should add multiple options.. like @ media only screen and (min-width : 992px) { and @ media only screen and (min-width : 1280px) { etc?

Comment: Basically it adapts to the window size not just screen size (re-sizing the browser window will also take affect). Thanks for the answer. Not the fluid design I hoped for, but it works for me.

Comment: @mspir thx for the correction . :) there might be a better solution using JS , will post an update if i find a better solution .